# Javascript that executes in an email that can grab the subject of the current email

Tags: javascript, email, html-email, mailto

I am trying to create an email that requests approval.  The way it currently works is that the user needs to reply to the existing email and type "APPROVE" OR "REJECT" as the first word of the body of the email.

Instead, I would like to create two buttons: "APPROVE" and "REJECT"

These buttons need to create a new email message with the appropriate title and body.

I know how to create the email, the only part I am missing is how can I grab the subject of the original email and use it in  the subject of the new reply email?

I need this to work in the following email clients:

1. Windows: Outlook 2007 & 2010 and Mac 2011
2. iPhone & iPad Email Client
3. Droid Email Client
4. Mac Email Client

Comment: Which email client(s) do you target ?

Comment: why don't you create links inside your mail that will be interpreted by the server instead of sending back an email ?

Comment: I need this to work in the following email clients:

    Windows: Outlook 2007 & 2010 and Mac 2011
    iPhone & iPad Email Client
    Droid Email Client
    Mac Email Client

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is not the appropriate way to accomplish this. Most email clients will prevent JS from executing. I suggest having two links in the email (maybe styled as buttons) so that the user can click "Approve" or "Deny". The links would be handled by some server-side code.

Alternatively, if you still want to send another email, you could use `mailto` in the anchor tag and utilize the `body` and `subject` parameters.

Comment: I can't handle this on the server side, since the email may be read when people do not have access to the private intranet.  I have successfully used the mailto: approach so far.  The only thing I need to do is set the subject correctly.  This involves obtaining the subject from the current email.  How can I do that?  The current email contains a Correlation Token, which I need to use in the subject of the new email.

Comment: If you're creating the email and adding the `mailto` already, don't you have access to the subject at the time that you create the email? How is the original email being generated?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript for that. Use `mailto:` links instead:

`<a href="mailto:person@place.com?subject=<YOUR SUBJECT>&body=<YOUR BODY>">`

Here's [the full syntax decription](http://www.ianr.unl.edu/internet/mailto.html).

Good luck!

Comment: The question was not what tech to use, the question was how to grab the subject of the original email. But good suggestion! =)

Comment: Well, if he's sending the email out, I guess he can grab it when he sends it.

Comment: I suspect the OP wants this to be a fairly automatic, non user-interaction-heavy process. But, sure.

Answer (score 0):

The below schema's work on the iPad, iTouch, outlook, gmail but NOT in "gmail in the browser" on the iPad. :(

You can do some basic html in the email no javascript so far.

```
Dear _______,
<br/>
<a href="mailto:bobo@larry.com?subject=tokenbbb=this is the body">APPROVE</a>
<br/>
<a href="mailto:bobo@larry.com?subject=my+subb&body=this is the body">REJECT</a>
Sincerely,
<br/>
```

If you mail the above to the client I believe everything will work for you.

Comment: Isn't this the same solution as pederOverland's? You're specifying that it doesn't work on the iPad, but it would have been better as a comment on his answer. Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way :-)